# Terraform missing when value should be passed in from tfvar file

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I have a `terraform` project which contains a main module and a submodule. Something like this:

```
\modules
 dev.tfvars
 \app
  \main
   main.tf, output.tf, providers.tf, variables.tf
  \sub-modules
   \eventbridge
    main.tf, output.tf, variables.tf
```

Both `variables.tf` files have this variable defined:

```
variable "secrets" {
    description = "map for secret manager"
    type = map(string)
}
```

The top level `main.tf` has this defined:

```
module "a-eventbridge-trigger" {
    source          = "../sub-modules/eventbridge"
    secrets         = var.secrets
}
```

The submodule `main.tf` has this:

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_connection" "auth" {
  name               = "request-token"
  description        = "Gets token"
  authorization_type = "OAUTH_CLIENT_CREDENTIALS"

  auth_parameters {
    oauth {
      authorization_endpoint = "${var.apiurl}"
      http_method            = "POST"

      oauth_http_parameters {
        body {
          key             = "grant_type"
          value           = "client_credentials"
          is_value_secret = true
        }
        
        body {
          key             = "client_id"
          value           = var.secrets.Client_Id
          is_value_secret = true
        }
        
        body {
          key             = "client_secret"
          value           = var.secrets.Client_Secret
          is_value_secret = true
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, when run it throws this error:

```
Error: error creating EventBridge connection (request-token): InvalidParameter: 2 validation error(s) found.
- missing required field, CreateConnectionInput.AuthParameters.OAuthParameters.ClientParameters.ClientID.
- missing required field, CreateConnectionInput.AuthParameters.OAuthParameters.ClientParameters.ClientSecret.
```

A file dump ahead of the `terrform apply` command successfully dumps out the contents of the `tfvars` file, so I know it exists at time of execution.

The top level `output.tf` successfully writes out the complete values of the `secrets` variable after execution, so I know the top level module receives the variables.

In the submodule, the resources defined after the `aws_cloudwatch_event_connection` block do get created and they also use variables received from the same tfvars file.

Is this a problem with how I am providing the variables or with my definition of the resources itself? (Or something else?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`client_parameters` is missing on your configuration, you need to set it in `auth_parameters.oauth`

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_connection" "auth" {
  name               = "request-token"
  description        = "Gets token"
  authorization_type = "OAUTH_CLIENT_CREDENTIALS"

  auth_parameters {
    oauth {
      authorization_endpoint = "${var.apiurl}"
      http_method            = "POST"

      client_parameters {
        client_id     = var.secrets.Client_Id
        client_secret = var.secrets.Client_Secret
      }

      oauth_http_parameters {
        body {
          key             = "grant_type"
          value           = "client_credentials"
          is_value_secret = true
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```